# highcharts style modification in R

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I hope to change attributes in highcharts, which is a part of [rCharts R package](http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/). Also, I hope to do this by using R, not by web related or any other language.

In any highcharts example, we can see those default attributes under `style` tag are as follow:

```
 <style>
     .rChart {
          display: block;
          margin-left: auto; 
          margin-right: auto;
          width: 800px;
          height: 400px;
        }    
 </style>
```

I hope to modify this to:

```
<style>
    .rChart {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto; 
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute
    }  
</style>
```

I tried to find how to do this in the reference (https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/rcharts/latest/rcharts.pdf), but I could not find it. I'd appreciate if someone let me know this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to do it would be to generate the highcharts-specific code only and insert it in an HTML file containing your custom CSS. Otherwise, if you want to adjust the style direclty from R, you can access the `width` and `height` attributes of your chart through `chart$params$width` and `chart$params$height` respectively. However, it seems that you need to provide a value in **pixels**, hence my recommendation to adjust this property outside of rCharts.

Here is a small example, based on the code provided in the [quick start page](http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/) of the package's website, to adjust the width and height from R:

```
library(rCharts)
h1 <- hPlot(x = "Wr.Hnd", y = "NW.Hnd", data = MASS::survey, type = c("line", 
"bubble", "scatter"), group = "Clap", size = "Age")
h1$params$width <- 1000
h1$params$height <- 1000
print(h1) # Display the chart
```

If you want to get only the highcharts-specififc code (div + chart JS), for use in an external web page:

```
 chartCode <- capture.output(chart$print("chart_id"))
 chartCode <- paste(chartCode, collapse='') # If you want a single string containing the code, that can be exported as you please.
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, especially for a trick to fix specific code.